# E_FAIL{0X80004005} error while starting Ubuntu in oracle virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine

I am unable to start Ubuntu in oracle virtual box installed in windows 7 OS.I have imported .ova file.

this is the error message shown:

[image: pic]

Comment: Can you post the log-file mentioned in the error message ?

Comment: The log file was too long can you please tell me what exact information you want in log file?...

Comment: It's difficult to say, without seeing the log, but maybe the the last 20 - 50 lines. Or the lines around the time you trid to start the vm last time.

Comment: https://appuals.com/best-fix-steps-fix-error-0x80004005/ and it's obviously an Windows error and as such off-topic here. It being triggered by Virtualbox trying to run a Ubuntu VM doesn't make it on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after Windows updated itself.

On the virtualbox.org forums, they provide a few steps: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=82106

However, that didnt help.

What did help, was updating VirtualBox from 5.1.22 to 5.2.6. My hypothesis here was that Windows had updated some `dll`s so I need to update VirtualBox so that its compatible with the new `dll`s.